# C# detect extraneous files

Tags: c#, file, detect

I have **folder** with these files:

- image1.png
- image2.png
- image3.png
- image4.png
- image5.png

And I need to check is exists extraneous files in this folder, for example if I create **example.file.css** I need to give an error, there must be only that files which listed above. So i've created needed files string:

```
string[] only_these_files = { 
    "image1.png", 
    "image2.png", 
    "image3.png",
    "image4.png",
    "image5.png"
};
```

Now I need to search for extraneous files, but how to? Thanks immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Use Directory.GetFiles:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx

And compare with your list of allowed files.

```
    string[] only_these_files = { 
        "image1.png", 
        "image2.png", 
        "image3.png",
        "image4.png",
        "image5.png"
    };
    string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);

    List<String> badFiles = new List<string>();

    foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        if (!only_these_files.Contains(fileName))
        {
            badFiles.Add(fileName);
        }
```

Comment: i think it would be more helpful if you add a code example

Comment: Thanks so much, but I'm newbie in this language (C#), i need code :(

Comment: This is pretty much what you need.
All the unwanted files is in the List badFiles. If it's empty you're all set.

Comment: If this answers your question you should mark it as Accepted answer (and maybe go through your history and mark answers for your other questions aswell).

Answer (score 0):

This would be my implementation with the use of a lil' LINQ

```
        var onlyAllowedFiles = new List<string>
        { 
            "image1.png", 
            "image2.png", 
            "image3.png",
            "image4.png",
            "image5.png"
        };

        var path = "";
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

        var nonAllowedFiles = files.Where(f => onlyAllowedFiles.Contains(f) == false);
```

Or alternatively if you wish to only detect the presence of illegal files.

```
        var errorState = files.Any(f => onlyAllowedFiles.Contains(f) == false);
```

Comment: Thank you, how can I check it now? I'm tried something like this:
if(errorState == true){MessageBox.Show("Please delete non allowed files!");} And it's not worked for me

Comment: Why post a duplicate answer..?

Comment: @Jonas Was fiddling with it while you answered. Non-intentional, rly. However I guess my solution is slighty different. @Dewagg you'll need to replace the path variable with the directory which you are inspecting - as like  `var path = @"C:\the\path\to\your\directory"`